# How to filter objects in Django models.py using querysets from views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I need to show the ratings left by one User for another User for a post that the member has written. The models.py are below. I have  3 functions in my models.py

`def average_rating(self):`, `def total_ratings(self):`, `def total_posts(self)` All 3 of these functions use the forloop `Review.objects.all():` which I believe may be wrong. In my views.py I have the context as

```
 Review.objects.filter(review_for__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return context
```

I thought that the views will filter the ratings of the user that belong to the person getting rated. Example if there are 4 ratings 2 for Admin and 2 for other users. If I see Admins Profile page. The template should show only the average ratings of the 2 ratings for the admin. Instead it shows average of all 4 ratings (2 for Admin and 2 for other un-related users). How can I fix this

Below are my **models.py**

```
class Review (models.Model):
        review_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_from')
        review_for = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_for')
        item = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, related_name='items')
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        feedback = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        feedback_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
        feedback_video = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
        rating_choices = (
            ('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two'), ('3', 'Three'), ('4', 'Four'), ('5', 'Five'),
            ('6', 'Six'), ('7', 'Seven'), ('8', 'Eight'), ('9', 'Nine'), ('10', 'Ten')
        )
        ratings = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=rating_choices)

        def __str__(self):
            return 'Review from {} to {} for {}'.format(self.review_from, self.review_for, self.item.tasting)

        def average_rating(self):
            counter = 0
            total_ratings = 0
            for item in Review.objects.all():
                counter += 1
                total_ratings += int(item.ratings)
                user_rating = total_ratings / counter
            return user_rating

        def total_ratings(self):
            counter = 0
            for item in Review.objects.all():
                counter += 1
            return counter

        def total_posts(self):
             for postin Review.objects.all():
                  all_posts= [post.item.tasting]
             unique_posts= set(all_posts)
        return len(unique_posts)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```

**Views.py are:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context['review_list'] = Review.objects.filter(review_for__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return context
```

**Templates are:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    Average rating for {{user.first_name|title}} {{user.last_name|title}} is {{user.review.average_rating}}
    {% for review in review_list|slice:":1" %}
    <b>{{ review.average_rating }}</b> based on <b>{{ review.total_ratings }}</b> ratings for {{ review.total_posts }}
    post{{ review.total_posts|pluralize }}
    <br/><br/>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for review in review_list %}
        <video width="400" controls>
          <source src="{{ review.feedback_video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video><br/><br/>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for review in review_list %}
        <img src="{{ review.feedback_image.url }}" width="400px"><br/><br/>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

changed the forloop from

```
Review.objects.all()
```

to

```
for recipe in Review.objects.filter(review_for=self.review_for):
```